# How does Swift converts a string to UTF-8 Representation?

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

The Swift documentation discusses the following code:

```
let dogString = "Dog‼"
for codeUnit in dogString.utf8 {
    print("\(codeUnit) ", terminator: "")
}
print("")
// Prints "68 111 103 226 128 188 240 159 144 182 ”
```

Then it mentions that:

> “The next three decimal codeUnit values (226, 128, 188) are a three-byte UTF-8 representation of the DOUBLE EXCLAMATION MARK character.”

But how this value of (226, 128, 188) was obtained? What calculation is going on behind the scene?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The fourth character in the string is a [double exclamation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203c/index.htm). It's Unicode code point U+203C.

In UTF-8, this code point is converted into a sequence of three code units (or bytes in this case), namely 226, 128, 188.

The [Wikipedia page for UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) describes the encoding. In particular have a look at the example with the Euro sign (€), which is also converted to a three byte sequence.